# Unittest that every element matches in 2 lists

Tags: python, list, unit-testing, comparison

Unit testing that 2 lists are the same in Python. Seems like it fails if they're not in order. Thought about sorting them first or converting to a set. But the set method isn't true, if there's duplicate etc

```
l1 = ['c-00355', 'b-0ae53', 'c-07d32']
l2 = ['b-0ae53', 'c-07d32' ,'c-00355']

l1 == l2
False

set(l1) == set(l2)
True

sorted(l1) == sorted(l2)
True
```

Comment: Sorting them will work just fine in your case

Comment: Yeah sorting the list does work, I was hoping for a more Pythonic way that's readable for the next soul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe consider a `collections.Counter` - it's a kind of cross between a `set` and a list sort and then comparing it... it's `__eq__` method checks each key is present in both and that the quantities match, eg:

```
from collections import Counter                                                   

l1 = ['c-00355', 'b-0ae53', 'c-07d32']                                            
l2 = ['b-0ae53', 'c-07d32' ,'c-00355']                                            

Counter(l1) == Counter(l2)                                                        
# True

l2 = ['b-0ae53', 'c-07d32' ,'c-00355', 'c']                                       

Counter(l1) == Counter(l2)                                                        
# False
```

Comment: Neat I didn't know about `collections.Counter` , I've always just made a dictionary with the key then incremented the value, but I see Counter has a bunch of other methods available too.

Comment: @SelfishCosmonaut it's pretty much the same as that approach but it just does some of the background work for you... plus has some overridden methods that only make sense with ints as its possible values etc... (so you can do `Counter(l1) + Counter(l2)` which can make sense with ints as the values, rather than a normal `dict` that could contain anything as values etc...)